# for loop keeps repeating output in python script

Tags: python, for-loop, virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I have written a script to list the VMs in our Azure subscription and I've noticed that the list keeps repeating itself until I cancel the run.

The script is below:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential 


subscription_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)

def list_vms_in_subscription():
    group_list = compute_client.resource_skus.list()
    for group in list(group_list):
        list_vms_in_groups(group.name)

def list_vms_in_groups(group_name):
    for resource in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        if resource.type == "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines":
            print(resource.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_vms_in_subscription()
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using your `group_name` parameter in your `list_vms_in_groups` method. So for each group, you're listing all VMs for all groups. It shouldn't go on forever, but it will return all resources x number of times (where x is the number of groups in your subscription)

Answer (score 2):

The `list_vms_in_groups` function ignores the group name and instead lists all the VMs:

```py
def list_vms_in_groups(group_name):
    for resource in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(group_name):
        # Here ------------------------------------------^
        if resource.type == "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines":
            print(resource.name)
```

Comment: I tried that, so I get the following error:
line 29, in <module>
    list_vms_in_subscription()
line 15, in list_vms_in_subscription
    list_vms_in_groups(group.name)
line 18, in list_vms_in_groups
    for resource in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all(group_name):

TypeError: VirtualMachinesOperations.list_all() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @DanielJ - from the error it looks like you're still calling `list_all`, not `list`.

Answer (score 2):

`resource_skus.list` method returns the SKUs available (for your subscription), not the resource groups or the VMs themselves. `list_vms_in_subscription:` should iterate over groups in `resource_client.resource_groups.list` and then call `list_vms_in_group` with the group name. `list_vms_in_group`  then iterate the VMs in `compute_client.virtual_machines.list`. Try something like this:

```
def list_vms_in_subscription():
    for group in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
        list_vms_in_group(group.name)

def list_vms_in_group(group_name):
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(group_name):
        print(vm.name)
```

Comment: @DanielJ that's great, I'm happy that I was able to help. Please consider marking it as the accepted answer (just click the tick mark on the left). Also, an upvote would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

subscription_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)

def list_vms_in_subscription():
    group_list = compute_client.resource_groups.list()
    for group in group_list:
        list_vms_in_group(group.name)

def list_vms_in_group(group_name):
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(group_name):
        print(vm.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_vms_in_subscription()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).